# Protocol buffer serialization of List

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

What's wrong with the following code?

```
MyList l = Serializer.DeepClone(new MyList { "abc" });
Console.WriteLine(l.Count == 1);
```

Where:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyList : List<String>
{
}
```

Expected: true, actual: false.

Comment: Streaming it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ooh, that's intriguing. I'm not at a PC tonight, but will look tomorrow.

Comment: (I agree that *at first glance* it looks like it should work, unless you have "IgnoreListHandling" specified in the ProtoContract, which you do not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an immediate fix, just take away the `[ProtoContract]`; lists have inbuilt behaviour, and don't need to be marked as contracts.

It *looks* like in this case the contract definition is taking precedence over the fact that it is a list; I will need to look carefully to see if changing this causes any unwanted side-effects.

Working example:

```
public class MyList : List<string>{}

[Test]        
public void ListSubclassShouldRoundTrip()
{
    var list = new MyList { "abc" };
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(list);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, clone.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc", clone[0]);
}
```

currently broken example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyContractList : List<string> { }

[Test]
public void ContractListSubclassShouldRoundTrip()
{
    var list = new MyContractList { "abc" };
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(list);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, clone.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc", clone[0]);
}
```

---

Update; however, it looks like this *should* work, since it works fine when the list is a **member** of a type; the problem only occurs when the list is the **outermost** type in a graph. Example (all tests pass):

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ListWrapper
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<string> BasicList { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public MyList MyList { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public MyContractList MyContractList { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void TestBasicListAsMember()
{
    var obj = new ListWrapper { BasicList = new List<string> { "abc" } };
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
    Assert.IsNull(clone.MyList);
    Assert.IsNull(clone.MyContractList);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, clone.BasicList.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc", clone.BasicList[0]);
}

[Test]
public void TestMyListAsMember()
{
    var obj = new ListWrapper { MyList = new MyList { "abc" } };
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
    Assert.IsNull(clone.BasicList);
    Assert.IsNull(clone.MyContractList);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, clone.MyList.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc", clone.MyList[0]);
}

[Test]
public void TestMyContractListAsMember()
{
    var obj = new ListWrapper { MyContractList = new MyContractList { "abc" } };
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
    Assert.IsNull(clone.BasicList);
    Assert.IsNull(clone.MyList);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, clone.MyContractList.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc", clone.MyContractList[0]);
}
```

---

Update update: this was a subtle bug, caused by the many different ways that lists can behave; in the case of lists as members that have getters and setters, it has some logic that says "if we get the list, and it wasn't null, don't call the setter - just add". However, the code that handles types-that-are-lists was accidentally enabling that mode. So what was happening was: it would deserialize the data, then proclaim "you can discard this value" - which it dutifully did. Then the "never return null" code would just create a new list, and return *that* instead. Annoyingly, just a one-liner to fix, and no side-effects; fixed in r555.

Whenever someone gets stuck, I [add an integration test; so this shouldn't happen again](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Examples/Issues/SO11656439.cs)

Comment: @Oron emphasis: the fix is I the source too now, but you'll have to build from source

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished a project myself where I was working with Protobut and used about 30different Protocontracts in the project and just reviewed this because I thought I'd done similar, but infact I'd never done this particular case directly.

So I just knocked up this as a test, but you may be able to use it for your purposes. (Yeah it's VB, but i'm currently quicker knocking up VB vs C# [but i'm getting there])

The results were not what I expected, so I posted my tests here. Maybe you could implement the Class with Internal list (to get you through for now).

> Mylist ProtoBuf False
>
> Mylist BinaryFormatter True
>
> Mylist2 ProtoBuf True
>
> MyListI ProtoBuf False
>
> MyListThing ProtoBuf False

```
Imports System.IO

Imports ProtoBuf

Public Class Entry
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim l As New MyList
        l.Add("abc")
        Dim newList As MyList

        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            Serializer.Serialize(Of MyList)(ms, l)
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            newList = Serializer.Deserialize(Of MyList)(ms)
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine("Mylist ProtoBuf {0}", newList.Count = 1)

        Dim f As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            f.Serialize(ms, l)
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            newList = CType(f.Deserialize(ms), MyList)
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine("Mylist BinaryFormatter {0}", newList.Count = 1)

        Dim l2 As New MyList2
        l2.Items.Add("abc")
        Dim newList2 As MyList2

        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            Serializer.Serialize(Of MyList2)(ms, l2)
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            newList2 = Serializer.Deserialize(Of MyList2)(ms)
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine("Mylist2 ProtoBuf {0}", newList2.Items.Count = 1)

        Dim li As New MyListI
        li.Add(5)
        Dim newListi As MyListI

        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            Serializer.Serialize(Of MyListI)(ms, li)
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            newListi = Serializer.Deserialize(Of MyListI)(ms)
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine("MyListI ProtoBuf {0}", newListi.Count = 1)

        Dim lh As New MyListThing
        lh.Add(New Thing() With {.Message = "abc"})
        Dim newListh As MyListThing

        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            Serializer.Serialize(Of MyListThing)(ms, lh)
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            newListh = Serializer.Deserialize(Of MyListThing)(ms)
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine("MyListThing ProtoBuf {0}", newListh.Count = 1)
    End Sub
End Class

<ProtoContract(), Serializable()>
Public Class MyList
    Inherits List(Of String)
End Class

<ProtoContract()>
Public Class MyList2
    Public Sub New()
        Items = New List(Of String)
    End Sub
    <ProtoMember(1)>
    Public Property Items As List(Of String)
End Class

<ProtoContract()>
Public Class MyListI
    Inherits List(Of Integer)
End Class

<ProtoContract()>
Public Class MyListThing
    Inherits List(Of Thing)
End Class

<ProtoContract()>
Public Class Thing
    <ProtoMember(1)>
    Public Property Message As String
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Paul,
Thanks for sharing your code.
Unfortunately, Your workaround isn't good for my needs. I am converting an existing code to GPB and therefore, cannot change the structure of the class. It's also something that Marc may want to look into since it's a basic functionality that may not work as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure he'll be looking at it, was just hoping you'd be able to work around it :-(